# Why PHP APC cache miss in increasing all the time

Tags: php, apc, php4, opcode-cache

I am using apc.php to check the PHP APC's stats (http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/trunk/apc.php)

I have the following stats on a fairly busy server

```
Cached Files    317 ( 26.3 MBytes)
Hits    51483
Misses  6814
```

The problem is the **Misses** is always increasing (given a limited number of files), are there any way to check which files are missed?

Another question is: The Cached Files is total consuming 26.3MBytes, does it mean every Apache child process is using 26.3MBytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do know what apc does, don't you?

You would expect the misses to go up in a caching situation? If you have stale cache, or just cold cache, you get a miss, the cache gets filled, and the next time (until it expires) you get a hit.

The total cached amount (the 26.3 mb) is the amount of files in your cache. This has nothing to do with apache children, this is the amount of info that is saved for quick access..